# Problems with variable $_POST on yii

Tags: ajax, forms, yii, http-post, cgridview

I make a `cgridview` with one column editable for update data, [based on this post](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/353/working-with-cgridview-in-admin-panel/).

With only a button (update licencias) to update all the fields in an ajax call.

But it only updates the first field.

I think that something is happened on `$_POST` variable.

I try several ways to look looping the `$_POST` variable unsuccessfully.

My code:

View:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>


<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'rta-client-grid',
    'selectableRows'=>1,
    'selectionChanged'=>'mostrarDetalles',  // via 1: para mostrar detalles al seleccionar
    'dataProvider'=>$modelClient->search(),
    'filter'=>$modelClient,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'id'=>'autoId',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => '50',
        ),
        'oid',
        'name',
        'surname',
        'id_country',
        'nif',
        //'CifDni',
        array(
            'name'=>'CifDni',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'CHtml::textField("CifDni[$data->oid]",$data->CifDni,array("style"=>"width:80px;"))',
            //
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{detallarClientes}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'detallarClientes'=>array(
                    'label'=>'ver',
                    'imageUrl'=>'images/demo1/view.png',
                    'click'=>'js:mostrarDetalles',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
)); ?>

<script>
    function reloadGrid(data) {
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('rta-client-grid');
    }
</script>
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Filter',array('rtaClient/ajaxupdate'), array(),array("style"=>"display:none;")); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Update licencias',array('rtaClient/ajaxupdate','act'=>'doUpdateLicencia'), array('success'=>'reloadGrid'),array("style"=>"float:right;")); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionAjaxupdate()
{
    $act = $_GET['act'];
    if($act=='doUpdateLicencia')
    {
        $sortOrderAll = $_POST['CifDni'];
        if(count($sortOrderAll)>0)
        {
            foreach($sortOrderAll as $menuId=>$sortOrder)
            {
                $model=$this->loadModel($menuId);
                $model->CifDni = $sortOrder;
                $model->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Post variable on FirebugConsole:

```
CifDni[10]  H
CifDni[11]  I
CifDni[12]  J
CifDni[2]   A
CifDni[3]   B
CifDni[4]   C
CifDni[6]   D
CifDni[7]   E
CifDni[8]   F
CifDni[9]   G
RtaClient[CifDni]   
RtaClient[id_country]   
RtaClient[name] 
RtaClient[nif]  
RtaClient[oid]  
RtaClient[surname]
```

---

I Just solved the problem. I modified the controller adding:

```
    foreach($_POST as $id=>$value)
    {
        if($id=="CifDni") {
            foreach($value as $id2=>$value2)
            {
                $model=$this->loadModel($id2);
                $model->CifDni = $value2;
                $model->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

But the problem in base was in other field (non showed on the grid) that has the rules 'required' and in the database has not value and they don't let me update by SQL error (the sql error don't appears in the log).

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        //array('pass', 'required'), //<----
```

Comment: In your case, does it meant that record which has oid=10 (first one) would be updated but oid=11,12,....2,3,4 did not?

Comment: Hi @TelvinNguyen, I just solved the problem. I was in the data on table and rules on the model.

Answer (score 0):

```
$model->save(false);
```

To force save your model without validating through your rule instead of removing your rule on model.